# Reduce code length

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I want to have multiple independent slideshows in the same webpage I have this script and is working well but I want to know is there a shorter way to make this because I need to add five more slideshows to the page I used this example from [w3 slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  "use strict";
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("comment-box");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.margin = "0 auto";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```js
var slideIndex1 = 1;
showSlides1(slideIndex1);

function plusSlides1(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides1(slideIndex1 += n);
}

function currentSlide1(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides1(slideIndex1 = n);
}

function showSlides1(n) {
  "use strict";
  var j;
  var slides1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-box1");
  var dots1 = document.getElementsByClassName("dot1");
  if (n > slides1.length) {
    slideIndex1 = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex1 = slides1.length;
  }
  for (j = 0; j < slides1.length; j++) {
    slides1[j].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (j = 0; j < dots1.length; j++) {
    dots1[j].className = dots1[j].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides1[slideIndex1 - 1].style.display = "block";
  slides1[slideIndex1 - 1].style.margin = "0 auto";
  dots1[slideIndex1 - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```js
var slideIndex2 = 1;
showSlides2(slideIndex2);

function plusSlides2(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides2(slideIndex2 += n);
}

function currentSlide2(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides2(slideIndex2 = n);
}

function showSlides2(n) {
  "use strict";
  var k;
  var slides2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-box2");
  var dots2 = document.getElementsByClassName("dot2");
  if (n > slides2.length) {
    slideIndex2 = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex2 = slides2.length;
  }
  for (k = 0; k < slides2.length; k++) {
    slides2[k].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (k = 0; k < dots2.length; k++) {
    dots2[k].className = dots2[k].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides2[slideIndex2 - 1].style.display = "block";
  slides2[slideIndex2 - 1].style.margin = "0 auto";
  dots2[slideIndex2 - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```js
var slideIndex3 = 1;
showSlides3(slideIndex3);

function plusSlides3(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides3(slideIndex3 += n);
}

function currentSlide3(n) {
  "use strict";
  showSlides3(slideIndex3 = n);
}

function showSlides3(n) {
  "use strict";
  var l;
  var slides3 = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-box3");
  var dots3 = document.getElementsByClassName("dot3");
  if (n > slides3.length) {
    slideIndex3 = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex3 = slides3.length;
  }
  for (l = 0; l < slides3.length; l++) {
    slides3[l].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (l = 0; l < dots3.length; l++) {
    dots3[l].className = dots3[l].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides3[slideIndex3 - 1].style.display = "block";
  slides3[slideIndex3 - 1].style.margin = "0 auto";
  dots3[slideIndex3 - 1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of sliders out there already.

Comment: If you tidy up your question, I think it's more suitable on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as it's about working code. Also "*making the code shorter*" might be a bit too little information.

Comment: Look at all that duplicated code! Use an array/dictionary to hold all your slides and an index to remember what slice you are at. Then you only need one `showSlides(n)` method, not one per slide (and so on).

Comment: Im new to javascript and w3 have easy to follow examples I tried with others but I couldnt get them to work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could convert the first (dynamic block) into a JavaScript object/class structure.

Then you can create five or more instances of a Slideshow and each one will have its own index to keep track of the current slide. Each function will be a method on the object instead, so they should be independent of each other.

```js
function Slideshow(options) {
  this.slideIndex = 1;
  this.slideClass = options.slideClass;
  this.dotClass = options.dotClass;
}

Slideshow.prototype.plusSlides = function(n) {
  this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
}
Slideshow.prototype.currentSlide = function(n) {
  this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
}
Slideshow.prototype.showSlides = function(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName(this.slideClass);
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName(this.dotClass);
  if (n > slides.length) {
    this.slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    this.slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.margin = "0 auto";
  dots[this.slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

Usage

```js
var mySlideshow = new Slideshow({
  slideClass : "comment-box",
  dotClass : "dot"
});
mySlideshow.showSlides(mySlideshow.slideIndex);
```

---

### Demo

Here is a demo showing two slideshows running concurrently.

```js
function Slideshow(options) {
  this.slideIndex = 1;
  this.selector = options.selector;
  this.el = document.getElementById(options.id);
  this.createListeners();
  this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);
}
Slideshow.prototype.createListeners = function(n) {
  var self = this;  
  var dots = self.el.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-dot');
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    self.createDotListener(dots[i], i + 1);
  }
  self.el.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-prev')[0]
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      self.plusSlides(-1);
    });
  self.el.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-next')[0]
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      self.plusSlides(1);
    });
};
Slideshow.prototype.createDotListener = function(dot, index) {
  var self = this;
  dot.addEventListener('click', function() {
    return self.currentSlide(index);
  });
};
Slideshow.prototype.plusSlides = function(n) {
  this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
};
Slideshow.prototype.currentSlide = function(n) {
  this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
};
Slideshow.prototype.showSlides = function(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = this.el.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-slide');
  var dots = this.el.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-dot');
  if (n > slides.length) {
    this.slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    this.slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
  slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.margin = '0 auto';
  dots[this.slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
};

var mySlideshow1 = new Slideshow({ id : 'my-slideshow-1' });
var mySlideshow2 = new Slideshow({ id : 'my-slideshow-2' });
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.slideshow-slide {
    display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.slideshow-prev, .slideshow-next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.slideshow-next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.slideshow-prev:hover, .slideshow-next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.slideshow-dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div id="my-slideshow-1">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="slideshow-slide fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-slide fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-slide fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    <a class="slideshow-prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="slideshow-next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="slideshow-dot"></span> 
    <span class="slideshow-dot"></span> 
    <span class="slideshow-dot"></span> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="my-slideshow-2">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="slideshow-slide fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-slide fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-slide fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    <a class="slideshow-prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="slideshow-next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="slideshow-dot"></span> 
    <span class="slideshow-dot"></span> 
    <span class="slideshow-dot"></span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Marco88 I added a demo. I added the listeners dynamically.